# Method for FileUpload throwing errors in Java-Windows

Tags: java

I want to test one sample program for file Uploading.But it is showing error "FileNotFoundException".

```
   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class TestUpload {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public boolean handleFileUpload(){


        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        boolean isFileUplodedCorrectly = true;
        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\vishu.jpeg")));
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\vishuGreetings.jpeg")));


            byte[] b = new byte[1024];

            while (bis.read(b) != -1)
                bos.write(b);
            bos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isFileUplodedCorrectly = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Exception in FileUpload Utils " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return isFileUplodedCorrectly;

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TestUpload tu=new TestUpload();
    System.out.println("Status"+tu.handleFileUpload());

    }

}
```

Actually the file is present there. Please Check.

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\vishuGreetings.jpeg (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at TestUpload.handleFileUpload(TestUpload.java:23)
    at TestUpload.main(TestUpload.java:52)
Exception in FileUpload Utils java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\vishuGreetings.jpeg (The system cannot find the file specified)Statusfalse
```

The file D:/vishuGreetings.jpeg is present there.But I am getting a File Not Found Exception for the same.Please check the code provided and revert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by giving .jpg instead of jpeg and found it working fine.When I check the properties of the file it is jpeg. that is why I used the extension jpeg in the file nmae in the code.Sorry for the trouble.